# How can I compare the first row of my excel file to the values stored in a variable to see if they are matched or not?

Tags: c#, excel

I need to open pre existing excel file and edit that excel file.

Comment: 1. Do you want to compare each cell in one row against variable ? 2.How Your input look like - add to question? 3. Whats You desired output ?

Comment: @KubaDo please see the comment and updated question